# How to calculate inductance (ferrite core) in a induction heater

Tags: mosfet, inductance, zvs

this is my third tag and I´m going to accurate my question, I have builded four induction heater and only one works, I´m sure that´s because of the inductor L1, I do not know how to obtain te correct value (I blew up four mosfets). Please help Me

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY8gnU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of your previous question "[Calculate inductance of chokes for a induction heater](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/414740)" which is also related to your first question "[Trouble with my homemade induction heater](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/413703)". You can't keep asking the same question - duplicates are not allowed! [Here is the help page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) explaining what to do if no-one answers. It does *not* say to repeat the question again. I recommend you delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should edit your three synonymical questions into one better question, and as you don't seem to be having too much luck getting an answer thus far, really think about what you can do to improve it.  General advise is, organise, ensure every request for additional information in the comments is answered and added to the question if relevant.  Even if it's not a homework question, you'll have better results if you show more work.  You may in the end just have to break down and learn how your circuit works.  Compare inductance and other values on both working and broken circuits.

Comment: It´s not exactly the same question, now I have exposed my schematic and I asking for the inductors, not about MOSFETs exploding and overheating...I´m not having luck with the answers because nobody is answering. Now I think i´m being "clear as water" with the question. In a previous, I said that I was waiting for LM339 to make an "inductometer" with arduino, but that not resolves my problem, I would Know how to calculte the inductance I need.